# How to collect heap dump or Stack trace from a running typescript app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, stack, stack-trace, heap-dump

I have a running node app built with typescript framework and I have a requirement to collect the heap dump of the **running process** , I haven't added the package Heapdump or V8 engine so I can't in anyway modify the app. Is there a way to collect the stats from a running process ?